# How to calculate the difference between dates in R for each unique id

Tags: r

I am new to R and have the following data of user name and their usage date for a product (truncated output):

```
Name,  Date 
Jane,  01-24-2016 10:02:00
Mary,  01-01-2016 12:18:00
Mary,  01-01-2016 13:18:00
Mary,  01-02-2016 13:18:00
Jane,  01-23-2016 10:02:00
```

I would like to do some analysis on difference between `Date`, in particular the number of days between usage for each user. I'd like to plot a histogram to determine if there is a pattern among users.

1. how do I compute the difference between dates for each user in R ?
2. are there any other visualizations besides histograms I should explore ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your expected output (at least the data), and also what ordering are you using in the data given above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, assuming your data frame is `df`:

```
## in case you have different column names
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "Date")

## you might also have Date as factors when reading in data
## the following ensures it is character string
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)

## convert to Date object
## see ?strptime for various available format
## see ?as.Date for Date object
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")

## reorder, so that date are ascending (see Jane)
## this is necessary, otherwise negative number occur after differencing
## see ?order on ordering
df <- df[order(df$Name, df$Date), ]

## take day lags per person
## see ?diff for taking difference
## see ?tapply for applying FUN on grouped data
## as.integer() makes output clean
## if unsure, compare with: lags <- with(df, tapply(Date, Name, FUN = diff))
lags <- with(df, tapply(Date, Name, FUN = function (x) as.integer(diff(x))))
```

For you truncated data (with 5 rows), I get:

```
> lags
$Jane
[1] 1

$Mary
[1] 0 1
```

`lags` is a list. If you want to get Jane's information, do `lags$Jane`. To get a histogram, do `hist(lags$Jane)`. Furthermore, if you want to simply produce a histogram for all clients, overlooking individual difference, use `hist(unlist(lags))`. The `unlist()` collapse a list into a single vector.

---

**comments:**

1. regarding your requirement for good reference to R, see [CRAN: R intro](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) and [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/);
2. using `tapply` for multiple indices? Maybe you can try the trick I gave by using `paste` to first construct an auxiliary index;
3. Er, looks like I quickly made things complicated than necessary, by using `density` and central limit theorem, etc, for visualization. So I removed my other answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Zheyuan Li for the detailed explanation, It was very easy to follow your instructions and hints on the function to look up

Comment: Zheyuan Li: if I have another column "Id" that I want to apply the Diff function to, can I call tapply(Date, Name,Id, Fun = ...) ? I want to apply the function but on multiple columns

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear earlier. I want to be able to treat Name and ID as a combination. Only taking the difference when Name and ID are the same Would Tapply still be the right function?

Comment: Ah, that is a good trick. You are a great teacher. Can you recommend any good books to read on R ?

Comment: I have one last follow up questions. Let's say I want a histogram of the differences for all users. Would it be easier to use the library Akrun described below ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113095/discussion-between-user82383-and-zheyuan-li).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(mdy_hms(Date)),  .(Diff=as.integer(diff(as.Date(mdy_hms(Date))))), Name]
#    Name Diff
#1: Mary    0
#2: Mary    1
#3: Jane    1
```

If there are several grouping variables i.e.  "ID" , we can place it in the `by`

```
setDT(df1)[order(mdy_hms(Date)),  .(Diff=as.integer(diff(as.Date(mdy_hms(Date))))), 
                                        by = .(Name, ID)]
```